# how to use a static variable in a static functions of a struct

Tags: c++, struct, g++

following compiles fine with g++:

```
struct acounter {

  long static counter;

  void static create() {  //reset or create the counter
    counter=0;
  }

  void static count() {   //the counter changes its internal value.
    counter=counter + 1;
  }   

};


int main(int   argc,  char *argv[] ){    //compiles and executes!
  //do some random stuff...
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is: as soon as I add "acounter::create();" or "acounter::count();" to the main loop, I get an error:

> undefined reference to `acounter::counter'

But I defined "counter" and even initialize it. What is the problem?

(P.S. I can only use static functions as I have to deal with callbacks later - the idea is to use the whole struct only on its global scope without creating instances.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static class members need to be *defined* as well as declared. While we're at it, we can *initialize* the static member to the right value, so no more need for "create" - but we could feasibly have a "reset" logic.

Also, if you're actually exposing the logic via static functions, the counter itself should be private.

Finally, as a matter of style, the `static` keyword is usually placed before the type name. It's a matter of taste, but it's a rather important attribute and one should be able to quickly tell static and non-static members apart when looking at a class definition.

```
struct acounter
{
private:
  static long counter;
public:
  static void reset() { counter = 0; }
  static void count() { ++counter; }
};

long acounter::counter = 0;   // definition and initial value

int main()
{
  acounter::count();
}
```

Comment: I thought it was common practice, rather than a matter of taste, to place keywords like `static` first.

Comment: @Chiffa: Well, I'd say so, too, but I can't speak for everyone. I think it's definitely more readable, and I've never seen anything else in "real" codebases...

Comment: Thanks, perfect answer - that one extra line did it.

Comment: @Kenobi: Yep, it does. Just be sure to have only *one* definition in your program (i.e. put that line into a single translation unit only).

Answer (score 0):

Put this into `*.cpp`:

```
long acounter::counter;
```

**NOTE:** You might want to initialize it as well, for example:

```
long acounter::counter = 0;
```

`static`, but non-`const` data members should be defined outside of the class/struct definition and inside the namespace enclosing the class/struct. The usual practice is to define it in the translation unit (`*.cpp`) because it is considered to be an implementation detail.

Extract from **section 9.4.2 of the C++ Standard**:

> The definition for a static data member shall appear in a namespace scope enclosing the member’s class definition.

There is also another way. Only `static` and `const` integral types can be declared and defined at the same time (inside class/struct definition):

```
class Example {
public:
  static const long x = 101;
};
```

in this case you don't need to add `x` definition because it is already defined inside the class/struct definition. In your case, `long` is integral type, but not `const` so you cannot opt to this approach.